# Org column-view with visual-line-mode?

Tags: org-mode, wrapping, visual-line-mode

I want to enable visual-line-mode for use with org-column-view, so that the text under each headline wraps underneath. Here is a sample "shopping list" to illustrate what I mean:

[image]

Notice how the item's description extends to the full width of the buffer but wraps for readability. I was able to get this to work by calling `visual-line-mode` after I ran column view. So I would love to find a hook that lets me load this from init, something like this:

```
(setq 'org-column-view-hook 'visual-line-mode)
```

Can't find an `org-column-view-hook` though..?

I've also noticed that if I make any changes to the view (e.g., hitting "<" or ">" to adjust the column width) then visual-line-mode is immediately disabled... anyway ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: The function you use to activate is probably `M-x org-columns`.  Since it doesn't have a hook, you could just make a new function that calls `(org-columns)` with the optional argument if so desired; and, then call your own settings -- e.g., `(setq truncate-lines nil word-wrap t)`.  Like this:  `(defun adam-fn () (interactive) (org-columns) (setq truncate-lines nil word-wrap t))`  If you type `M-x find-function RET org-columns RET`, you will see that down towards the end of the function, `truncate-lines` is set to `t` -- and that is what is causing the behavior you experience . . .

Comment: In addition to the above-comment, you could also use `advice` -- but I rarely use it.  Most people seem to prefer `advice` instead of creating a new function, but I'm not sure why that is.  In general, `visual-line-mode` and `org-mode` do not play well together.  I turn on `visual-line-mode` in a few limited circumstances where I am familiar with the combined behavior -- e.g., when I am editing a task in a narrowed indirect buffer.

Comment: Thanks @lawlist, this works great! I added `(defun adam-fn () (interactive) (org-columns) (setq truncate-lines nil word-wrap t))` to my init.el file, followed by `(define-key (current-global-map) [remap org-columns] 'adam-fn)` so I can use `C-c C-x C-c` to launch the modified mode.